# Using LINQ to split items within a list

Tags: c#, linq

I want to separate each item in a list, but also within each item, split the item if it contains `:`

eg.

```
string[] names = {"Peter:John:Connor","Paul","Mary:Blythe"};
name.Dump();
```

Will show:

```
Peter:John:Connor
Paul
Mary:Blythe
```

However, is there any LINQ that I can use, which will provide the following list:

```
Peter
John
Connor
Paul
Mary
Blythe
```

I can do this using:

```
foreach (var person in names)
{
    x = person.split(":").ToList();
    foreach (var personinlist in x)
    {
        // personinlist
    }
}
```

...but that seems very long winded, when I'm certain LINQ could be more elegant.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) to flatten results of splitting each name by `:`

```
names.SelectMany(n => n.Split(':'))
     .Dump();
```

Comment: @IlyaIvanov thanks! I always forget that splitting by strings require new array, and do same for chars :) I'll try to remember that

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
names = names.SelectMany(n => n.Split(':')).ToArray();
```